# React: how to set default value in component from Ajax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to create form for editing existing value. The problem is the initial data which comes from ajax request and as result my component is rendred twice: first with empty values and second when the data comes.
Currenly my code doesn't put received data in form. How can I set obtained data from ajax request in form as init data with posibily edit in futher in this form ?

My component that is responsible for input in form:

```
export default class FormInputField extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value : constants.EMPTY_FIELD,
        errorDisplay : constants.DISPLAY_NONE,
        errorMessage : constants.MESSAGE_DEFAULT_ERROR,
    }
    this.validation = this.validation.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
}

handleChange(e){
    let valid = this.validation(e.target.value);
    if (this.props.onChange){
        this.props.onChange(e, valid)
    }
}

validation(value){
    //some validation        
    this.setState({
        value : value,
        errorDisplay : errorDisplay,
        errorMessage : errorMessage
    })
    return valid;
}

handleBlur(e) {
    this.validation(e.target.value.trim());
}

    render(){
    return(
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor = {this.props.name}>{this.props.title}</label>
            <div className="col-sm-10">

                <input name={this.props.name}
                       type="text" className="form-control"
                       id={this.props.name}
                       placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                       value={this.state.value}
                       onChange={this.handleChange}
                       onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

This component is call form `Parent` component by following way:

```
return(
        <div style={mainFormStyle}>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="addCarWashForm">

                <FormInputField
                    title = "Name*:"
                    placeholder = "Name"
                    name = "name"
                    onChange = {this.handleNameChange}
                    required = {true}
                    maxLength = {50}
                    validation = {this.validationName}
                    errorMessage = "Error"
                    defaultValue = {this.state.name.value}
                />
```

and default value comes from the same `Parant` state which is set by this way:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name        :  {value : constants.EMPTY_FIELD, isValid : false}
        isCarWashDownload : false
    };
    this.setCarWashInForm = this.setCarWashInForm.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount(){
    if (!this.state.isCarWashDownload){
        let link = "/carwash/"+this.props.carWashId;
        this.serverRequest = $.get(link, function (result) {
            this.setCarWashInForm(result);
        }.bind(this));
    }

};

setCarWashInForm(carWash){
    this.setState({
        name : {value : carWash.name, isValid:true},
        isCarWashDownload : true
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Children** component is rerendering when its props are change by **Parent** component, so render in Children and Parent run twice, on initial data, and after `setState` in ajax call response callback ( because state properties in Parent are set as props of Children ). You can avoid rendering Children component by doing simple `if` in render method of Parent class.

```
render(){

    let input=null; //or some loading component to show that something is going on

    if (this.ajaxEnded) //example variable which should be changed on true when data is loaded from ajax call
    input=<FormInputField
                title = "Name*:"
                placeholder = "Name"
                name = "name"
                onChange = {this.handleNameChange}
                required = {true}
                maxLength = {50}
                validation = {this.validationName}
                errorMessage = "Error"
                defaultValue = {this.state.name.value}
            />      

   return(

     <div style={mainFormStyle}>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="addCarWashForm">
        {input}
        </form>
     </div>

  );

 }
```

So we show nothing or loading in first `render`, in ajax call we set some variable representing that data was loaded as boolean true and second `render` call shows wanted final children component.

Answer (score 1):

Since the ajax call is async, you have a couple options:

1. You have standard defaults that show up until the date comes back and those get overridden.
2. While the ajax call is taking place initially you don't actually render the form and once the call finishes you render the form with that data.

Depending on where the form lives and what you want your user experience would be major factors to consider to either approach.

What you are experiencing now is that the ajax call goes out, react skips to the render function and renders the form before the ajax call finishes, once it finishes the component updates its state and then rerenders.

Comment: Can you explain how rendering be blocked untill the ajax request wil befinished ?

Comment: So for that I would have a default state of loading = true, and then in your render method just have a `if (loading) { return <LoadingComponent /> } else { return <FormInputField /> }` and then have some sort of loading component you want to put there, or you could just have it return `null` and then it wont show anything at all until the data comes back.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was usefull but I accept another answer because it has more clear an exaple, I think it will be usefull for rest uses